# Java Applet only running in NetBeans 8.1 won't run in Eclipse and BlueJ

Tags: java, html, swing, netbeans, applet

I have to make a Java JApplet similar to the Air India online e-ticket booking system. I made one with a javax.swing NetBeans design editor, and when I run it from within the NetBeans Application, it runs fine. However, if I copy the exact same code, end-to-end to Eclipse or BlueJ, the Applet doesn't even show up on the screen.

I embedded this Applet into the HTML page with all three methods I know of (applet, object and embed tags) but no luck... I believe that the applet tag is deprecated, but it doesn't run even with the other tags.

Please help soon... (I need to turn it in by April 20th)

Here's my entire code:

```
package util_Pkg;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class AirIndia extends JApplet implements ItemListener, ActionListener
{
@Override
public void init() 
{
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AirIndia.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>


    /* Create and display the applet */
    try 
    {
        EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                initComponents();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    Calendar1.addActionListener(this);
    Calendar2.addActionListener(this);
    RoundTrip.setSelected(true);
    OneWay.addItemListener(this);
    RoundTrip.addItemListener(this);
    Depart.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
        {
            Depart.setText("");
        }
    });
    Return.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
        {
            Return.setText("");
        }            
    });
    FromPlace=(String) fromBox.getSelectedItem();
    ToPlace=(String) fromBox.getSelectedItem();
    numOfAdult=Integer.parseInt((String)numOfAdults.getSelectedItem());
    numOfChild=Integer.parseInt((String)numOfChildren.getSelectedItem());
    numOfInfant=Integer.parseInt((String)numOfInfants.getSelectedItem());
    seatType=(String) flightClass.getSelectedItem();
    DateChosenDeparture=(String) Depart.getText();
    DateChosenReturn=(String) Return.getText();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    numOfAdults = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
    numOfChildren = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
    numOfInfants = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
    flightClass = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
    fromBox = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
    toBox = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();

    Panel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

    OneWay.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    flightType.add(OneWay);
    OneWay.setText("One Way");

    RoundTrip.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    flightType.add(RoundTrip);
    RoundTrip.setText("Round Trip");
    RoundTrip.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));

    fromLabel.setText("From");

    toLabel.setText("To");

    classLabel.setText("Class");

    AdultsLabel.setText("Adults");

    ChildrenLabel.setText("Children");

    InfantLabel.setText("Infants");

    Depart.setText("DD/MM/YYYY");

    Return.setText("DD/MM/YYYY");

    numOfAdults.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" }));
    numOfAdults.setSelectedIndex(1);

    numOfChildren.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" }));

    numOfInfants.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" }));

    flightClass.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Economy", "Business", "Executive" }));

    fromBox.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Select...", "Hamid Karzai International Airport, Kabul", "Sydney Airport, Sydney", "Melbourne Airport, Melbourne", "Vienna International Airport, Vienna", "Bahrain International Airport, Manama", "Shahjalal International Airport, Dhaka", "Shanghai Pudong International Airport, Shanghai", "Charles de Gaulle Airport, Paris", "Frankfurt Airport, Frankfurt", "Hong Kong International Airport, Hing Kong", "Veer Savarkar International Airport, Port Blair", "Visakhapatnam Airport, Visakhapatnam", "Vijayawada Airport, Vijayawada", "Tirupati Airport, Tirupati", "Lokpriya Gopinath Bordoloi International Airport, Guwahati", "Dibrugarh Airport, Dibrugarh", "Raxaul Airport[T], Raxaul", "Lok Nayak Jayaprakash Airport, Patna", "Gaya Airport, Gaya", "Chandigarh Airport, Chandigarh", "Swami Vivekananda Airport, Raipur", "Indira Gandhi International Airport, New Delhi", "Goa International Airport, Goa", "Vadodara Airport, Vadodara", "Surat Airport, Surat", "Sardar Vallabhbhai Patel International Airport, Ahmedabad", "Srinagar Airport, Srinagar", "Leh Kushok Bakula Rimpochee Airport, Leh", "Jammu Airport, Jammu", "Birsa Munda Airport, Ranchi", "Mangalore Airport, Mangalore", "Kempegowda International Airport, Bangalore", "Bellary Airport, Bellary", "Trivandrum International Airport, Thiruvananthapuram", "Cochin International Airport, Kochi", "Calicut International Airport, Kozhikode", "Khajuraho Airport, Khajurao", "Devi Ahilyabai Holkar Airport, Indore", "Bhopal Airport, Bhopal", "Pune Airport, Pune", "Dr. Babasaheb Ambedkar International Airport, Nagpur", "Chhatrapati Shivaji International Airport, Mumbai", "Aurangabad Airport, Aurangabad", "Tulihal International Airport, Imphal", "Lengpui Airport, Aizawl", "Dimapur Airport, Dimapur", "Biju Patnaik International Airport, Bhubaneshwar", "Sri Guru Ram Dass Jee International Airport, Amritsar", "Udaipur Airport, Udaipur", "Jodhpur Airport, Jodhpur", "Jaipur International Airport, Jaipur", "Tiruchirapalli Airport [T], Tiruchirapalli", "Madurai Airport, Madurai", "Coimbatore International Airport, Coimbatore", "Chennai International Airport, Chennai", "Rajiv Gandhi International Airport, Hyderabad", "Agartala Airport, Agartala", "Lal Bahadur Shastri International Airport, Varanasi", "Chaudhary Charan Singh International Airport, Lucknow", "Agra Airport, Agra", "Netaji Subhas Chandra Bose International Airport, Kolkata", "Bagdogra Airport, Siliguri", "Milan-Malpensa Airport, Milan", "Leonardo da Vinci-Fiumicino Airport, Rome", "Narita International Airport, Tokyo", "Kansai International Airport, Osaka", "Incheon International Airport, Seoul", "Kuwait International Airport, Kuwait City", "Ibrahim Nasir International Airport, Malé", "Yangon International Airport, Yangon (Rangoon)", "Tribhuvan International Airport, Kathmandu", "Muscat International Airport, Muscat", "Domodedovo International Airport, Moscow", "King Khalid International Airport, Riyadh", "King Fahd International Airport, Dammam", "King Abdulaziz International Airport, Jeddah", "Singapore Changi Airport, Singapore", "Bandaranaike International Airport, Colombo", "Suvarnabhumi Airport, Bangkok", "Sharjah International Airport, Sharjah", "Dubai International Airport, Dubai", "Abu Dhabi International Airport, Abu Dhabi", "Heathrow Airport, London", "Birmingham Airport, Birmingham", "San Francisco International Airport, San Francisco", "O'Hare International Airport, Chicago", "Newark Liberty International Airport, Newark", "John F. Kennedy International Airport, New York City" }));

    toBox.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Select...", "Hamid Karzai International Airport, Kabul", "Sydney Airport, Sydney", "Melbourne Airport, Melbourne", "Vienna International Airport, Vienna", "Bahrain International Airport, Manama", "Shahjalal International Airport, Dhaka", "Shanghai Pudong International Airport, Shanghai", "Charles de Gaulle Airport, Paris", "Frankfurt Airport, Frankfurt", "Hong Kong International Airport, Hing Kong", "Veer Savarkar International Airport, Port Blair", "Visakhapatnam Airport, Visakhapatnam", "Vijayawada Airport, Vijayawada", "Tirupati Airport, Tirupati", "Lokpriya Gopinath Bordoloi International Airport, Guwahati", "Dibrugarh Airport, Dibrugarh", "Raxaul Airport[T], Raxaul", "Lok Nayak Jayaprakash Airport, Patna", "Gaya Airport, Gaya", "Chandigarh Airport, Chandigarh", "Swami Vivekananda Airport, Raipur", "Indira Gandhi International Airport, New Delhi", "Goa International Airport, Goa", "Vadodara Airport, Vadodara", "Surat Airport, Surat", "Sardar Vallabhbhai Patel International Airport, Ahmedabad", "Srinagar Airport, Srinagar", "Leh Kushok Bakula Rimpochee Airport, Leh", "Jammu Airport, Jammu", "Birsa Munda Airport, Ranchi", "Mangalore Airport, Mangalore", "Kempegowda International Airport, Bangalore", "Bellary Airport, Bellary", "Trivandrum International Airport, Thiruvananthapuram", "Cochin International Airport, Kochi", "Calicut International Airport, Kozhikode", "Khajuraho Airport, Khajurao", "Devi Ahilyabai Holkar Airport, Indore", "Bhopal Airport, Bhopal", "Pune Airport, Pune", "Dr. Babasaheb Ambedkar International Airport, Nagpur", "Chhatrapati Shivaji International Airport, Mumbai", "Aurangabad Airport, Aurangabad", "Tulihal International Airport, Imphal", "Lengpui Airport, Aizawl", "Dimapur Airport, Dimapur", "Biju Patnaik International Airport, Bhubaneshwar", "Sri Guru Ram Dass Jee International Airport, Amritsar", "Udaipur Airport, Udaipur", "Jodhpur Airport, Jodhpur", "Jaipur International Airport, Jaipur", "Tiruchirapalli Airport [T], Tiruchirapalli", "Madurai Airport, Madurai", "Coimbatore International Airport, Coimbatore", "Chennai International Airport, Chennai", "Rajiv Gandhi International Airport, Hyderabad", "Agartala Airport, Agartala", "Lal Bahadur Shastri International Airport, Varanasi", "Chaudhary Charan Singh International Airport, Lucknow", "Agra Airport, Agra", "Netaji Subhas Chandra Bose International Airport, Kolkata", "Bagdogra Airport, Siliguri", "Milan-Malpensa Airport, Milan", "Leonardo da Vinci-Fiumicino Airport, Rome", "Narita International Airport, Tokyo", "Kansai International Airport, Osaka", "Incheon International Airport, Seoul", "Kuwait International Airport, Kuwait City", "Ibrahim Nasir International Airport, Malé", "Yangon International Airport, Yangon (Rangoon)", "Tribhuvan International Airport, Kathmandu", "Muscat International Airport, Muscat", "Domodedovo International Airport, Moscow", "King Khalid International Airport, Riyadh", "King Fahd International Airport, Dammam", "King Abdulaziz International Airport, Jeddah", "Singapore Changi Airport, Singapore", "Bandaranaike International Airport, Colombo", "Suvarnabhumi Airport, Bangkok", "Sharjah International Airport, Sharjah", "Dubai International Airport, Dubai", "Abu Dhabi International Airport, Abu Dhabi", "Heathrow Airport, London", "Birmingham Airport, Birmingham", "San Francisco International Airport, San Francisco", "O'Hare International Airport, Chicago", "Newark Liberty International Airport, Newark", "John F. Kennedy International Airport, New York City" }));

    departLabel.setText("Departure");

    returnLabel.setText("Return");

    Calendar1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/util_Pkg/calendar-128.png"))); // NOI18N

    Calendar2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/util_Pkg/calendar-128.png"))); // NOI18N

    FlyAirIndiaBtn.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 51));
    FlyAirIndiaBtn.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    FlyAirIndiaBtn.setText("Fly AirIndia");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout PanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(Panel);
    Panel.setLayout(PanelLayout);
    PanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        PanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(PanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(PanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(PanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(PanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(departLabel)
                        .addComponent(Depart, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 128, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGroup(PanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(16, 16, 16)
                    .addGroup(PanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(PanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(OneWay)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(RoundTrip))
                        .addGroup(PanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                            .addGroup(PanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(flightClass, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 87, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGroup(PanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGroup(PanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addComponent(numOfAdults, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addComponent(AdultsLabel)
                                        .addComponent(classLabel))
                                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                    .addGroup(PanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addGroup(PanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                            .addComponent(numOfChildren, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                            .addComponent(numOfInfants, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                        .addGroup(PanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                            .addComponent(ChildrenLabel)
                                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                            .addGroup(PanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                .addGroup(PanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                    .addComponent(Calendar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 24, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                    .addGroup(PanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                        .addComponent(returnLabel)
                                                        .addGroup(PanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                            .addComponent(Return, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 128, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                            .addGroup(PanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                                .addComponent(FlyAirIndiaBtn)
                                                                .addComponent(Calendar2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 24, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))))
                                                .addComponent(InfantLabel)))))))))
                .addGroup(PanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(PanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addGroup(PanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(toLabel)
                            .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                            .addComponent(toBox, 0, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGroup(PanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(fromLabel)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(fromBox, 0, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))))
            .addContainerGap(14, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    PanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        PanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(PanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(16, 16, 16)
            .addGroup(PanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(OneWay)
                .addComponent(RoundTrip))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(PanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(fromLabel)
                .addComponent(fromBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(PanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(toLabel)
                .addComponent(toBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(PanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(departLabel)
                .addComponent(returnLabel))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(PanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(PanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(PanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(Depart, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(Calendar2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 20, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(Return, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(31, 31, 31)
                    .addGroup(PanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(AdultsLabel)
                        .addComponent(ChildrenLabel)
                        .addComponent(InfantLabel))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(PanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(numOfAdults, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(numOfInfants, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(numOfChildren, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(classLabel)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(PanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(flightClass, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(FlyAirIndiaBtn)))
                .addComponent(Calendar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 20, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(30, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(Panel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(Panel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
}// </editor-fold>                        

@Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evnt)
{

    if (evnt.getItemSelectable()==RoundTrip)
    {
        Return.setEnabled(true);
    }
    else
    {
        Return.setEnabled(false);
    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource()==Calendar1||e.getSource()==Calendar2)
    {
        Calendar dateChk=new Calendar();
        dateChk.main();
    }
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
public final javax.swing.JLabel AdultsLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
public final javax.swing.JButton Calendar1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
public final javax.swing.JButton Calendar2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
public final javax.swing.JLabel ChildrenLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
public final javax.swing.JTextField Depart = new javax.swing.JTextField();
public final javax.swing.JButton FlyAirIndiaBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
public final javax.swing.JLabel InfantLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
public final javax.swing.JRadioButton OneWay = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
public final javax.swing.JPanel Panel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
public final javax.swing.JTextField Return = new javax.swing.JTextField();
public final javax.swing.JRadioButton RoundTrip = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
public final javax.swing.JLabel classLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
public final javax.swing.JLabel departLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> flightClass;
public final javax.swing.ButtonGroup flightType = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> fromBox;
public final javax.swing.JLabel fromLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> numOfAdults;
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> numOfChildren;
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> numOfInfants;
public final javax.swing.JLabel returnLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> toBox;
public final javax.swing.JLabel toLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
// End of variables declaration                   
public String FromPlace, ToPlace, seatType, DateChosenDeparture, DateChosenReturn;
public int numOfAdult, numOfChild, numOfInfant;
}
```

The Calendar Class is known to work, so no worries about that. I don't have enough characters to add the html.

Comment: Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: 1) `Calendar dateChk=new Calendar();` For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556).

Comment: BTW - after 1) setting a security manager (which might be different between the different environments tested) 2) replacing the image icons with default 'black' images, & 3) commenting out all reference to the `Calendar` - I saw the applet on-screen. Are you somehow ignoring exception output? BTW - 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). ..

Comment: .. 2) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

Comment: *"I made one with a javax.swing NetBeans design editor"* - would probably be your first mistake

Comment: @MadProgrammer While true, I doubt it's the cause of the immediate problem. BTW - thanks for those links - I (think) I pretty much copy/pasted your common advice re applets into my little 'instant comment' app. ;-)

Comment: @AndrewThompson It really worked!? Was it opened with the applet viewer or an html page? And is it absolutely compulsory to use java nomenclature (cause if it's useful i will)? Sorry about the image, but that was really all I knew. Thanks for the tutorial...

Comment: @AndrewThompson I tried after doing exactly what you did (commenting out the calendar lines, adding a security manager and replacing icons with a black icon). Still didn't work when I compiled it with javac in cmd. So probably not problem with code, right?

Comment: *"..or an html page?"* Wait, what? Is that what Eclipse and BlueJ use to show applets? (That is not a rhetorical question, BTW - I'm curious) Be sure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show.  If there is no output at the default level, raise the level and try it again.